# Transparent colors wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have some Label control that sits on some image , and i want to give that control back ground Background="LightGray" but i also want it to be Transparent .

of course i can do Background="Transperent" but then i want to have something like green + Transperent .

Any idea how i do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush.opacity.aspx) property of your brush.  That should give you the semi-transparency you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A Background property takes Brush instance. If you analyze the Brush object you can see the first 2 byte is for the Alpha-transparency and the rest is RGB colors. 
  Here if you change 'FF' (255) to '7F'(127) you get half opaque so adjust that value and get your desired one. I would recommend to use Expression Blend for this kind of editing.